# How to update a django filter to django 1.2 with GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Hi I got the following filter which worked with django 0.96 (GAE) and is generating code on the layout erroneoulsy with GAE + django 1.2. Now i want to update the filter so that it works with django 1.2. COuld you provide any information please kindly do so.

Filter:

```
def news(n):
    url = os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') else os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
    tld = url[url.rfind('.'):]    
    try:        
        if url == 'localhost:8080' or url.endswith('alltfunkar.com'):
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.se/?output=rss')    
        elif tld != '.com' and tld != '.se' and tld != '.cl' :
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com'+tld+'/?output=rss') 
        else:        
        #result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google'+tld+'/?output=rss')
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')        
        if result.status_code == 200:
            dom = minidom.parseString(result.content)
            item_node = dom.getElementsByTagName("item")
            try:
                random_1=random.choice(item_node)
                rss1_link = random_1.childNodes[1].firstChild.data
                rss1_text = random_1.childNodes[0].firstChild.data
                return '<a href="'+rss1_link+'">'+rss1_text+'</a>'
            except IndexError,e:
                return ''
    except urlfetch.Error, e:
        pass

register.filter(news)
```

Template usage

```
{{a|news|fix_ampersands|truncatewords_html:8}
```

Solved and done with help here! Many thanks:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it would have helped if you'd specified exactly what was "erroneous" about the output you're getting.

My *guess* is that it's autoescaped, as you would know if you'd read the guide to upgrading from 0.96 to 1.0. Mark the output as safe:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...
return mark_safe('<a href="'+rss1_link+'">'+rss1_text+'</a>')
```

or, more Pythonically:

```
return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (rss1_link, rss2_text))
```

Comment: Perfect with the slight modification rss2_text really is called rss1_text since the 2 are text and link. Many thanks!